# Оператор as в php?

Tags: php

Что делает (какую функцию выполняет) оператор as в языке PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используется в цикле `foreach` для перебора всех элементов ассоциативного массива. [Тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php) подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

В PHP нет такого [оператора](http://php.net/operators).